# How can I set the font and the colour for a Button's text in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is my code below, The button's background is green, but I want to set the button text ("Done") to be white and 12 font.

```
from tkinter import *

def done(root):
  root.destroy()

def panel():
  root = Tk()
  root.title("PCS Employee Login")
  root.geometry('240x320+0+0')
  root.configure(bg='white')

  buttonDone = Button(root, text="Done", command=lambda: done(root))
  buttonDone.configure(bg='green', borderwidth=0)
  buttonDone.pack()

  root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
  panel()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extract of code that I used for creating buttons and labels in tkinter. I create three font variables detailing small, normal and large font, then call these variables as needed. For the button and lable colours you can use bg for the background colour and fg for the foreground (text) colour.

```
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT = ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Verdana", 8)

label = tk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT, bg='white', justify='left')
B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy, bg='#000000', fg='#ffffff')
```

[This page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) will give you more options for button configuration.

Comment: the 'fg' function is what I want, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A `Button`'s background is the button itself, and its foreground is the text or bitmap on top of it. Use the `foreground` option as described on [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm).

Comment: I know how to change the button's background color, I just need to change the color of text in the button. And your answer is helpful, thank you very much

Comment: Yes, the `foreground` option changes the text color. I only mentioned the background to explain what part of a `Button` it refers to.